# Падает ошибка: UnicodeEncodeError at /

Tags: django

Падает ошибка в Django проекте 
UnicodeEncodeError at /contact/1/view
'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 28-33: ordinal not in range(128)

Соответственно ругается на рендеринг темплейта. 
Traceback ругается на следующую строку

views.py in single_contact

```
              'vcard_str': str(VCard(contact)),
```

Функция полностью:

```
def single_contact(request, pk):
contact = Contact.objects.get(pk = pk)
if contact.group.user != request.user.profile:
    raise Http404
if request.method=="GET":
    emails = Email.objects.filter(contact = contact)
    hash = ''
    if emails:
        email = emails[0]
        hash = get_hash(email.email)
    addresses = Address.objects.filter(contact = contact)
    if addresses:
        address = addresses[0]
    phones = PhoneNumber.objects.filter(contact=contact)
    return render(request, 'dashboard/addressbook/single_contact.html',
            RequestContext(request, {
                'contact':contact, 'emails':emails, 'hash':hash,
                'addresses':addresses, 'phones':phones,
                'vcard_str': str(VCard(contact)),
            }))
elif request.method=="POST":
    contact.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('addressbook_index'))
else:
    raise Http404
```

Answer (score 0):

Если используется python 2 то необходимо использовать функцию unicode заместо str

```
'vcard_str': unicode(VCard(contact)),
```

Comment: Поправил. Однако, проблема сохранилась.
Текст ошибки: UnicodeDecodeError at /contact/1/view

'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 28: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @tonyjasta ИМХО надо явно передать кодировку через decode. Например VCard(contact).decode('utf-8'). Иначе питон не знает как интерпретировать байты.